# how to use html5 video landscape in ios

Tags: ios, html, landscape

I use phonegap to create a ios project.I want to use htmlt5 video to play a video in landscape.
So there is a way from webkit or in my application to switch in landscape mode only when i showing a HTML5 video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create view and add webView as subview to that view. Set orientation of that view to LandscapeLeft and LandScapeRight and load HTML5 video on webview. call that view when ever you want to play video; view will always appear in landscape mode.